# Access 2007, INSERT INTO (...) Values (...) throws Syntax error

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2007

```
INSERT INTO Employees (fname, lname, address, city, state, zip, phone)
VALUES ('Gustavo', 'Fring’, "125 Birdy Lane", ‘Tucson’, ‘AZ’, #85705#, #520-535-5323#);
```

> Error code: "Syntax error in query expression "Fring’, "125 Birdy Lane", ‘Tucson’, ‘AZ’, #85705#, #520-535-5323#);.

For the life of me I can not figure this out.

Comment: Its better to elaborate on what you are trying to achieve. As I am reviewing here I have to tell you this.

Comment: I am trying to insert a new row with new values into the Employees table

Answer (score 4):

Are the hash symbols `#` supposed to be part of the inserted strings?

Also you need to use normal single quotes `''` for all strings, not typographic ones `‘’`.

```
VALUES ('Gustavo', 'Fring', '125 Birdy Lane', 'Tucson', 'AZ', '85705', '520-535-5323')
```

Comment: Your solution worked, however now it is showing: Microsoft Access set 0 fields to Null due to a type conversion failure, and it didn't add 1 record to the table due to key violations, 0 records due to lock violations, and 0 records due to validation rule violations. Ignore errors?

Comment: The message is pretty clear. You can't insert the record if it violates a key of the table. As these keys are defined by you, you just have to clear that up.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you are putting  `"` around the address and `#` around the numbers. Doesn't `'` work?

Comment: <Message> in query expression <expression>. (Error 3075) 

The expression you typed is not valid for the reason indicated in the message. Make sure you have typed field names and punctuation correctly, and then try the operation again.
When I tried with just '

Comment: But my answer is the same as the one from @Andre , I'm not sure why this isn't working then. Make sure you use `'` and not that other one (not sure where you qwerty guys find that :P )

Comment: I can't comment on the other question, so I'm asking it here.

What are the types of your columns?